# can't upload picture with aws4 in react native while same request in python is working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, react-native

My task is to upload a picture to an API via react native. The authentication is done by AWS but without cognito. So I am requesting a role via aws.sts.requestRoleWithSAML witch is working so far. Now I sign my request with AWS Signature Version 4 Key by using the module 'aws4-react-native' and then sending a fetch-post request to the API.
But I just can't get it to work. The error message I receive is:

"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."

So maybe I am doing something wrong here but what I really don't understand is the fact that I got a fully working python example.

Maybe someone can help me with this problem or simply can provide me with information how to convert the python part into javascript fro RN.

python code:

```
client = boto3.client('sts')
temp_credentials = client.assume_role_with_saml(
            RoleArn='xxxxxx',
            PrincipalArn=''xxxxx',
            SAMLAssertion=saml_response)

auth = AWSRequestsAuth(
   aws_access_key=temp_credentials['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
   aws_secret_access_key=temp_credentials['Credentials']
                                      ['SecretAccessKey'],
   aws_host='xxxxx',
   aws_region='us-east-1',
   aws_service='execute-api',
   aws_token=temp_credentials['Credentials']['SessionToken'])

   URL = 'xxxxx'
   files = {'picture': open('IMG_20180326_193921.jpg', 'rb')}
header = {
   "version_code": "1",
   "crop": "MAIZE",
   "device_locale": "US",
   "date": "20180427_173034",
   "peat_id": "200001",
   "user_id": "fakeid25-e6a2-4e0c-9514-ccf429973af5",
   "pla_id": "fakeid05-19ab-4896-b748-e1c1ab99b1a9",
   "pic_id": "fakeidee-752f-42f0-a4e7-3e3e6fed9d76",
   "images_captured": "1",
   "images_uploaded": "0",
   "latitude": "10.15",
   "longitude": "10.15",
   "accuracy": "364",
   "file_name": "my-photo.tif",
   "app_locale": "US",
   "email": "some.person@pioneer.com",
   "user_name": "username",
   "confidence": "HIGH",
   "severity": "HIGH",
   "identifier": "Fake Image",
   "notes": "Blah blah blah"
}
response = requests.post(URL, files=files, headers=header, auth=auth)
```

react-native code:

```
const data = new FomrData();
data.append('picture', { uri: 'path/to/test.jpg', name: 'test.jpg', 
                        type: 'image/jpg' });
let temp = data.Credentials
let keyID = temp.AccessKeyId
let secretKey = temp.SecretAccessKey
let st = temp.SessionToken

var opts = {
    host: 'xxxxx',
    path: '/image_analysis',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    service: 'execute-api',
    headers: {
       'Host': 'xxxxx',
       'version_code': '1',
       'crop': 'MAIZE',
       'device_locale': 'US',
       'date': '20180427_173034',
       'peat_id': '200001',
       'user_id': 'fakeid25-e6a2-4e0c-9514-ccf429973af5',
       'pla_id': 'fakeid05-19ab-4896-b748-e1c1ab99b1a9',
       'pic_id': 'fakeidee-752f-42f0-a4e7-3e3e6fed9d76',
       'images_captured': '1',
       'images_uploaded': '0',
       'latitude': '10.15',
       'longitude': '10.15',
       'accuracy': '364',
       'file_name': imgname,
       'app_locale': 'US',
       'email': 'some.person@pioneer.com',
       'user_name': 'username',
       'confidence': 'HIGH',
       'severity': 'HIGH',
       'identifier': 'Fake Image',
       'notes': 'Blah blah blah',
       'X-Amz-Date': '20180518T133558Z',
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
}
fetch('https://xxxx', aws4.sign(opts, { secretAccessKey: secretKey, 
                             accessKeyId: keyID, sessionToken: st }))
.then(response => {res.text().then(t => console.log(t))});
```

This is just showing the fetch, the call for the credentials is working fine.

Hope anyone can help me here!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what the problem is. First of all this is not working like this at all. Reason for this is the bridge between javascript and native swift. This bridge does not allow to pass binary files. In other cases there is something like uploading files on an Amazon S3 server wich should work with their functions but in this case we needed to change the way. Our solution now is the switch from binary to base64. We had to change something on the server so I could upload base64 strings via the app.
Thanks to everyone who trying to help me out here!